# Can bevel do 45degree in edit mode?

Tags: bevel

1. I create Plane and adjust it to scale that I want.
2. Edit mode and extrude
3. I try to bevel 1 edge scale is correct but degree is fail.

So bevel can do the 45degree?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some things you could try, go into object mode and apply the scale using Ctrl+A > [Scale], before doing the bevel operation, or if that doesn't work you could try using the bevel modifier with a vertex group including the two vertices that make up your edge.

Answer (score 0):

Chose another Amount Type than Percent, because this is relative to the edge length. You will also need to adjust the value. Offset will do a 45 degree chamfer.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

You make a cut slide and drag it to make it square like. Use the grid to see it.

Now Select the vertice and use bevel until it hits the borders.

See the image below for shortcuts.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just select an edge, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> and adjust the bevel amount using the mouse.

[image: GIF]